# loading backbone.js resources based on authentication

Tags: security, authentication, backbone.js

I'm building my first backbone app, and though I'm doing my authentication server side, there are features that non-authenticated users are unable to use, but because they are in my asset path, and part of my backbone files, everything gets loaded.

Is there a way to load only the resources that a user is actually able to use?

I'm using Rails with cancan to manage this server-side.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the assets out in to separate groups: a group that can be used by anyone, and a group that can be used by authenticated users. Only send the code that the user is allowed to use, basically.

I wrote a post about doing this with asp.net mvc recently. the same idea applies to rails, though the use of the asset pipeline makes the implementation a bit different:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/01/26/modularity-and-security-in-composite-javascript-apps/

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a Base view with a property named `requireLogin: true/false`.

All other views should inherit this view and the views which need authentication you should set  `requireLogin:true`, for all others this property should be `false`.

After this you should handle the authentication base of this property.