# Loading backbone views based on authentication

Tags: backbone.js, view

While looking for solution I came across one example [here](https://github.com/Swiftam/book-node-mongodb-backbone/blob/master/ch10/public/js/views/login.js) where all other views are extended from a baseview

In base view

```
 define(function(require) {
   var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
   requireLogin: true
 });

 return AppView;
});
```

And in the extended views which don't need authenticaton put

```
  requireLogin: false
```

But couldn't find where and how is **requireLogin** implemented.

Also, in another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382904/loading-backbone-js-resources-based-on-authentication) the last answer suggests the same but doesn't talk about how to implement it.

**How can I use this?**

Comment: Where do you find your example?

Comment: requireLogin is just a property defined for each view.  You can use it pretty much however you want, but one possibility would be to add some code to the render() method where you check this property and if it's true, check that the user is authenticated.  If they're not, redirect them to the login page.

Comment: @JonathanNaguin I have updated the question with links to example and another stackoverflow question similar to this

Comment: @TNguyen What do you mean by check it in render method. What is the use of attribute if I am to check again if user is authenticated in the render method.                                                 Could you please provide me a pseudocode.

Comment: Based on that example code, I also don't see where they are implementing the requireLogin functionality.  In general though, what I mean is that you have to find some point in your code - before you render or show the view - where you can check that property and if it's true, check their authentication and redirect as necessary.

Comment: Thanks @TNguyen. I solved my problem based on your advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first, I'm going to assume that you did not use a plugin like super, so let me suggest it:
https://github.com/lukasolson/Backbone-Super

We want super to communicate with the parent view. Said that, do something like this:
(for simplicity I would not use define)

```
/*
  Whatever is your process for login, it should inject 
  this object with a true flag when logged
*/
var CredentialsCollector = {
    logged : false
};

var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

    requireLogin: true,

    render : function(){
        if( requireLogin && !CredentialsCollector.logged ){
            //do a redirect to your login module
        }
    }

});
var SomeView = AppView .extend({
    render : function(){
        /*
          this call the parent render to check the login; if required and not
          logged it automatically make the redirection
        */
        this._super();
        //<- here do your normal render stuff
    }

});
```

Comment: based on TNguyen suggestions (in comments) I have solved it. Mine solution is in a similar fashion described above in your solution. I was going to answer it myself, too late:D . But I will accept your answer for elaborate answer and pointing out to super plugin(I was doing it funky way). Thanks